# Java: Conditional Statement and relational Operators

Tags: java

I am struggling with the following task created by Jetbrains:

> Given three natural numbers A, B, C. Determine if a triangle with these sides can exist.
> If the triangle exists, output the YES string, and otherwise, output NO.
> A triangle is valid if the sum of its two sides is greater than the third side. If three sides are A, B and C, then three conditions should be met.
>
> 1. A + B > C
> 2. A + C > B
> 3. B + C > A

Sample Input 1:

```
3
4
5
```

Sample Output 1:

```
YES
```

Now, my code is following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
    
        boolean aCheck = b + c > a;
        boolean bCheck = a + c > b;
        boolean cCheck = a + b > c;
    
       if (aCheck || bCheck || cCheck) {
           System.out.println("YES");
       } else {
           System.out.println("NO");
       }
    }
}
```

Logically, everything seems correct, but I am getting errors on the Input

**1
2
3**

I am really not sure what i may have missed. Is my code incorrect?

Comment: Which errors do you get? Can you post them?

Comment: You've misread the prompt. Change `if (aCheck || bCheck || cCheck)` to `if (aCheck & bCheck & cCheck)`

Comment: What error are you getting? Please edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: That code does not seem to output any error. do you really mean you have an error or do you mean you don't get the correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code `if (aCheck || bCheck || cCheck)` passes if aCheck is true because it is based on the OR operator, for the triangle to be viable you need all the checks to pass. You should use the AND operator:

```
if (aCheck && bCheck && cCheck)
```

This was proposed by @sleepToken, on the comments, however, if you use `&&` instead of `&` it will fail as soon as some check is false.

Comment: Okay, but the Task is to check, if a triangle is possible and in the case "aCheck" it is. 
Hence, the if should be executed, because aCheck = true and only ONE condtion has to be true. 
Would using "&&" not always result in the code not to pass as there would be ALWAYS at least be one "false"? 
Am I not thinking logical?

Comment: Okay, HUGE missunderstanding on my end, I seem to have thought that only ONE Condition must be true but as stated in the Task ALL of them must be true, sorry. but thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition to:
if (aCheck && bCheck && cCheck) {}

If you want to stick to || operator then change it to:
if ( !(a+b<=c || b+c<=a || a+c<=b) ) {}

Peace out!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // start coding here
        int A = scanner.nextInt();
        int B = scanner.nextInt();
        int C = scanner.nextInt();
        if(A + B > C && A + C > B && B + C > A){
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

you should use `&&` instead of `||`